# How do I truncate tables in an MDF in SQL Express?

Tags: sql-server-express, truncate, staging, mdf, truncation

The command `EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'` returns the following error:

`The EXEC SQL construct or statement is not supported.`

[image]

I execute the query like this:

[image]

**Question**

> How do I erase all data, but keep existing tables, relationships, keys, and indexes settings?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off all constraints, delete all records, turn constraints back on:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘DELETE FROM ?’
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
GO
```